# Whether there is a way to encode the request url?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Whether there is a way to encode the request url?

Such as, I can use the url to request the Django/Django-Rest-Framework provides image:

```
https://localhost:8000/images/icon.png
```

whether I can use a Middleware or whatever to encode the url?

because if the `icon.png` is a `你好.png`, I want to encode the url to `utf-8`.

Whether it is feasible?

---

**EDIT-1**

I mean, in the Django backend, whether I can encode the url before it request?

There is a example:

```
https://www.google.com/images/icon.png
```

This url can request the backend, if the `google.com` use the Django as backend, whether I can get the request url before it query the backend, and then do something for the url, then let the url to request the backend? in the Django.

---

**EDIT-2**

I break the point in the first Middleware, but it do not get the breakpoint when I request the img request url directly in browser:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**EDIT-3**

This I put in the last middleware order:

```
class AccessControl(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):

        if 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD' in request.META:
            response = http.HttpResponse()
            response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]= "*"
            response["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true"
            response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"]= "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"
            response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Authentication , Authorization , X-CSRF-Token , " \
                                                       "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials , " \
                                                       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods , Access-Control-Allow-Origin , " \
                                                       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, " \
                                                       "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, " \
                                                       "Access-Control-Request-Headers"

            return response

        return None
```

Comment: `url.encode('utf8')`?

Comment: But I don't know where to encode it. whether in the middleware I can get the request url?

Comment: You can hook your logic in request-reponse cycle in the middleware. Django will receive your URL as unicode, so `你好.png` becomes `%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD.png ` as requested URL.

Comment: the middleware only have `def process_request(self, request):` `self` and `request` params, how can I get the url? does it in request?

Comment: Yes, you can use `request.path`. More details at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/

Answer (score -1):

Use `urllib` (python 2) or `urllib.parse` (python 3)

**Python 2**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import urllib
print urllib.quote_plus('你好.png')
```

**Python 3**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote_plus('你好.png')
```

---

Result:

```
%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD.png
```